# gluNewQuadric leaking memory

Tags: objective-c, opengl, memory-leaks, glut

When I checked my Application for leak with Instruments (X-Code Tool, I program in objective-c), I saw the #living "malloc 48 bytes" allocations growing bigger and bigger.
Also, Instruments does say that it leaks there. If I check for the Responsible caller, it always says "gluNewQuadric".
I checked the internet for a bit and found some people are having the same complaints, but not too many, and I also found no working solution.
I also put

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
```

in "main.m", and the increase of #living seems to have gone down a bit, but is still growing persistently.
The only place where I use glu is with

```
glutSolidSphere
glutWireSphere
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you calling `gluDeleteQuadric`?

Comment: No. What Quadric should I delete? glutSolidSphere seems to cause the problem, and gluNewQuadric is invoked inside glutSolidSphere, and I don't get the sphere as a return value or something...

Comment: Instead of `glut*Sphere` use `gluSphere` directly. Your glut implementation is probably not freeing `GLUquadricObj` correctly.

Comment: I've the same problem on OSX 10.6.8,  my solution was to substitute the glutSolidSphere call with the following:
`GLUquadricObj *quadricSphere=gluNewQuadric();`
`gluQuadricNormals(quadricSphere, GLU_SMOOTH);`
`glPushMatrix();`
`glTranslatef(x, y, z);`
`gluSphere(quadricSphere,radius,stacks, sectors);`
`glPopMatrix();`
`gluDeleteQuadric(quadricSphere);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pro-tipp: Don't use GLUT rendering primitives. They are there for quick testing and not meant for serious bussines. A few weeks ago I posted two lengthy answers on how to draw a sphere using pure OpenGL without resorting to GLU or GLUT:

- [Creating a 3D sphere in Opengl using Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988686/how-do-i-create-a-3d-sphere-in-opengl-using-visual-c/5989676#5989676)
- [How to animate a solid sphere over a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949248/how-to-animate-a-solid-sphere-over-a-curve/5949647#5949647)

Comment: That's some solution x)
But, with the help of your tutorial, I at least will be able to use Spheres further.
Thanks :)